# What happens when there is a quotation within a quotation within another quotation?

Tags: word-usage

For example: Kevin said to Ms.Russell: "Sam was mocking Dave by saying 'My name is Dave!**?** I'm so smart!**?**'"

*note that the question marks are what I'm wondering what I would put there

**note that Kevin is speaking

Comment: Who is asking the question? Sam or Kevin?

Comment: This is actually just a quotation within a quotation (there is no third quotation). What I often see in written text is the inner quote written in italics. Though using single + double quotes works too.

Comment: @maxpleaner OP doesn't know what to use for the third set of quotes, so they put question marks.

Comment: Oh thank you @Laurel i didnt catch that. Its still not really a third quote though. Its Kevin quoting Sam, who is _imitating_ Dave. Not quoting dave.

Answer (score 0):

You keep alternating between " and '.

I once said, "John told me, 'Do you know what Sally said?  She said, "David told me to give you message.  He said, 'Tell John the message that I give you.  Tell him, thus says David, "I will make known to you what was said by Mr. Smith in your Third Grade Class.  He said, 'Does anyone know what the color *orange* is made out of?'  He did not say, 'Does anyone know what the color *purple* is made out of?'"'"'"